# Convert list to array using toArray

Tags: java, arrays, list, dynamic-allocation

Please the read the question instead of assuming this is a duplicate.

In the codebase I am working on I have a list of Foo objects:

```
private List<Foo> fooList;
```

Could someone please explain to me the difference(s) between this line of code:

```
Foo foos[] = fooList.toArray(new Foo[fooList.size()]);
```

and this line?

```
Foo foos[] = (Foo[]) fooList.toArray();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is, 2nd one would throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime. The parameterless [`List#toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) method creates an `Object[]` internally, which you cannot cast to `Foo[]`. Since generic type information is erased by compiler, the type of the list is not known at runtime. So, you cannot know the actual type to create an array (i.e, you cannot create an array like - `new T[size]`). That is why it creates an `Object[]`.

To overcome this issue, a generic method [`List#toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) is there, in which you can pass the actual array, that will be filled by the elements of the `ArrayList`. If the size of the array is not enough to fit the elements, a new array is internally created. So, since you pass `new Foo[fooList.size()]`, it will get filled by the elements of the list. However, had you passed a `new Foo[0]`, a new array would have been created.

Comment: It's helpful to know about the runtime error on the 2nd line, but you don't explain what's happening in the first line.

Comment: @SoylentGreen Just expanded the answer.

Comment: Yes. Your explanation is better. @SoylentGreen note, that returned array may not be the same as given.

Answer (score 1):

Second method is wrong.

type of `fooList.toArray();` is Object[]

First method is typed. You creates new array with correct type and size (`new Foo[fooList.size()]`), and then, you filled it using `fooList.toArray()`

Also you can use `fooList.toArray(new Foo[0])` but this will give you an extra empty array object.

toArray works simple. If you call it without arguments, new Object[] is created.

If you give an array with correct type, it tryes to fill it, if it has enough space, or discard it, and create new array with given type.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking the difference between below methods;

```
list.toArray(array);
list.toArray();
```

First method will try to fit the elements in the list into the given `array` instance, if it fails then creates a new array and proceed. Also the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.

Second method creates a new array and proceed, and the return type is `Object[]` causing class cast exception in your example.

Comment: Thank you.  This is the explanation I needed for the first line of code.  I wanted to know why it created a new array.  Apparently it creates a new one on failure.

Comment: Although general consensus seems to indicate that the second method will fail during runtime...

Comment: Yes, since the Object[] is returned, it will result in an exception for sure. Hope you might consider marking this as the accepted answer then?

Answer (score -1):

`Using asList()` method

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Go to below link :
http://javaxtutorials.blogspot.in/p/converting-array-as-list-and-list-to.html